# createRange select all in parent js

Tags: javascript, range, selector

I'm looking to select a range with javascript `createRange` function. I'm just now after so many years discovering this function, and it's one of those DOH! moments.

Is there a way to select all the elements in a given parent. Currently, I have a div full of content I'm trying to select. This content may be text nodes, elements, IDK.

```
var container = document.getElementById('mydiv');
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(container, 0);
range.setEnd(container, ???);
```

Is there an accurate, easy, efficient way to get the length of content in the parent (`container`)? Or is there a hidden method with `range` that does this already?

No libraries, please! Not terribly concerned with cross-browser fall-backs, but insights into them are welcome if you have any.

**EDIT**

For clarity, I'm NOT looking to get the innerHTML, but rather a range object. So **PLEASE** don't say "why not just use innerHTML".

Comment: You could use `commonAncestorContainer`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/range.commonAncestorContainer . Please take a look at this site, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM , you can find all "hidden" properties =].

Comment: What do you mean by "the length of content in the parent"?

Comment: @TimDown I was trying to find a proper value to use in range.setEnd to select all the content. This is impractical and a solution already exists, as revealed in my answer to my own question >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectNodeContents` does the trick, getting the content of the specified element.

```
range.selectNodeContents(container);
```

Comment: `selectNodeContents` is what you want. I used it in my answer to your `innerHTML` question.

Comment: @TimDown That you did! I didn't even realize, I was using `range` looking through some docs (thanks to you!) and didn't even think to look back to my other scenario, which was the essentially the same idea in a different context.